# Camera is not launching from a hybrid app [Cordova]

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, crosswalk

For a hybrid android application developed with "Ionic" framework, I have been trying to launch camera with following

HTML: `<input type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera">`

But above lauches "Gallery" as default above ICS versions.

Have also tried with crosswalk webview, which naturally supports html5. Which is lauching "camcorder" and "document" application not camera :(.

Note: 
Loading html page with  is lauching camera in both chrome and Firefox browsers.

Cordova Version 6.3.1

Cordova Android Version 5.2.2

Crosswalk 18 - http://plugins.telerik.com/cordova/plugin/crosswalk

Any help would be appreciated.

[Click here to view the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nr5pN.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start with I haven't experienced this scenario myself I have to admit, because I always related on the Cordova camera plugin.

Just wrote a detailed description on how to use the camera plugin in Ionic, so implementing the photo capturing this way would be a solution for your case I guess.

Have a look at [the answer in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40513646/current-ionic-1-camera-plugin-implementation/40523946#40523946).

Don't hesitate to ask if any questions arise!